# SQL Server add null in where clause

Tags: sql, sql-server

I have this data:

```
+-----+-------+-------+-------+-------+
|  id |  val1 |  val2 |  val3 |  val4 |
+-----+-------+-------+-------+-------+
|   1 |     5 |  null |     0 |     3 |
+-----+-------+-------+-------+-------+
```

I want to select all rows where the added counts of val1-4 is above a certain threshold. However the columns are nullable. So this won't work:

```
SELECT * 
FROM data 
WHERE val1 + val2 + val3 + val4 > 6
```

I could use:

```
SELECT * 
FROM data 
WHERE ISNULL(val1, 0) + ISNULL(val2, 0) + ISNULL(val3, 0) + ISNULL(val4, 0) > 6
```

But I read that SQL Server cannot use indices when using `ISNULL` in a `WHERE` clause.

Is this true? What other options do I have?

Comment: What is the problem? Did you use `ISNULL` and it's taking to long ? Also, are all these columns indexed ?

Comment: SQL Server wouldn't be able to use index search anyway, because you are performing an addition on the columns. This is a full scan, perhaps of an index if all values are indexed together, but it's not an index look-up.

Comment: Yes bad thought process on my side.. of course indices won't help anyways. So I guess  ISNULL or COALESCE won't hurt the overall performance compared to not using it.

Answer (score 2):

I would use `coalesce()`:

```
SELECT *
FROM data
WHERE COALESCE(val1, 0) + COALESCE(val2, 0) + COALESCE(val3, 0) + COALESCE(val4, 0) > 6
```

Of course, SQL Server cannot use an index for this because of the functions.  Actually, it can't use the index with `+` either, so you haven't lost anything.

If you want to use an index, then add a computed column and a column on the index:

```
alter table data add total_value as
    (COALESCE(val1, 0) + COALESCE(val2, 0) + COALESCE(val3, 0) + COALESCE(val4, 0)) persisted;

create index idx_data_total_value on data(total_value);
```

Then phrase the query as:

```
where total_value > 6
```

Comment: Any reason you used COALESCE instead of ISNULL?

Comment: @Cosmin . . . It is ANSI standard functionality.  I realize that `ISNUL()` is more efficient under some circumstances, but this is not one of them.

Comment: @Cosmin I think you’ll find that `COALESCE` is the more standard solution — it’s in the ANSI standard.